# Difficulty with global symbols and explicit package names

Tags: perl

I'm in need of help debugging the code shown below. I've asked similar versions of this question, but I haven't been able to develop a script that works. My input file is like this:

> line1
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   line2
>   BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>   line3
>   CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
>   line4
>   DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

I would like the script to randomly shuffle the lines in the file, such as:

> line2
>       BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
>   line1
>       AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   line4
>       DDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
>   line3
>       CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

The file has quite a few lines in it (~1,000,000). Currently, I get the following errors:

```
Global symbol "$header_size" requires explicit package name at fasta_corrector9.pl line 40.
```

and

```
Global symbol "$header_size" requires explicit package name at fasta_corrector9.pl line 47.
```

I don't understand how to give `$header_size` an explicit package name. I'm not a programmer, so I'll need very basic explanations. Thanks in advance.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Please enter filename (without extension): ";
my $input = <>;
chomp($input);

print "Please enter total no. of sequence in fasta file: ";
my $orig_size = <> * 2 - 1;
chomp($orig_size);

open(INFILE, "$input.fasta") or die "Error opening input file for shuffling!";
open(SHUFFLED, ">" . "$input" . "_shuffled.fasta")
    or die "Error creating shuffled output file!";

my @array  = (0);    # Need to initialise 1st element in array1&2 for the shift function
my @array2 = (0);
my $i      = 1;
my $index  = 0;
my $index2 = 0;

while (my @line = <INFILE>) {
    while ($i <= $orig_size) {

        $array[$i] = $line[$index];
        $array[$i] =~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg;

        $index++;
        $array2[$i] = $line[$index];
        $array2[$i] =~ s/(.)\s/$1/seg;

        $i++;
        $index++;
    }
}

my $array  = shift(@array);
my $array2 = shift(@array2);
for $i (reverse 0 .. $header_size) {
    my $j = int rand($i + 1);
    next if $i == $j;
    @array[$i,  $j] = @array[$j,  $i];
    @array2[$i, $j] = @array2[$j, $i];
}

while ($index2 <= $header_size) {
    print SHUFFLED "$array[$index2]\n";
    print SHUFFLED "$array2[$index2]\n";
    $index2++;
}
close(INFILE);
close(SHUFFLED);
```

Comment: You actually want to use a lexical (`my $header_size;`) rather than use a package variable by explicitly specifying its package name (`$main::header_size`). You never gave a value to `$header_size` too. (I'm pretty sure I've brought up that problem in your code twice before!)

Comment: You mean like (for ($i = my $header_size; $i >= 0; $i--) {)  this? I was told this was incorrect. I don't know how to give a value (or what value to give) to $header_size

Comment: You need to assign a value to it before you use it in your `for`, so you need to the variable to exist sooner, so you'd have to declare it sooner. Again, YOU NEVER ASSIGN A VALUE TO `$header_size`, so you need `my $header_size = ...;` somewhere!!!

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, you are using `$header_size` in your code, but haven't told Perl what  `$header_size` exactly is. This is precisely why `use strict;` is *highly* recommended, otherwise it would have been silently treated as an undefined value (0 in numerical context).

[`perldoc perldiag`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) is useful in understanding such messages:

> **Global symbol "%s" requires explicit package name**
>
> (F) You've said "`use strict`" or "`use strict vars`", which indicates
>   that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "`my`" or
>   "`state`"), declared beforehand using "`our`", or explicitly qualified to
>   say which package the global variable is in (using "`::`").

Applying this to the problem at hand, `$header_size` has not been initialized. The thing to do in this case is to assign `my $header_size = $some_value;` before you use it, or simply `my $header_size;` if you really want to leave it undefined.

Comment: How can I initialize $header_size ?

Comment: listen to ikegami! Please ask questions, then listen. `my $header_size = 1000;` where `1000` is your header size. Honestly, how do you expect  there to be a value in this variable when you never give one to it?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this with a file of that size is to use [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) to allow random access to the lines of the data file

Using a mode of `O_RDWR` prevents the file from being created if it doesn't exist

In addition, the `shuffle` function from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) will allow you to randomly reorder the indices of the original file records

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;
use Fcntl 'O_RDWR';
use List::Util 'shuffle';

tie my @source, 'Tie::File', $ARGV[0], mode => O_RDWR, autochomp => 0
    or die "Unable to open file '$ARGV[0]': $!";

for my $line (shuffle 1 .. @source/2) {
  printf "line %d\n", $line;
  print $source[$line * 2 - 1];
}
```

This program should be run as

```
perl shuffle.pl infile > outfile
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Tie::File` be a memory hog for a file with a million lines?

Comment: I got my answer from the documentation: `"The file is not loaded into memory, so this will work even for gigantic files."`

Comment: That's awesome! It works perfectly well, with one problem. My lines are in pairs (line1 always goes with AAA, line2 always goes with BBB, etc.). This output does not keep the line pairs together. Can you suggest an alteration that would fix this problem?

Comment: @user1569630: I'm ahead of you! Sorry - I minsunderstood your question until you reformatted the data

Comment: Changed again to explicitly print the correct `line 99` instead of taking the string from the file

Comment: @Borodin, you are the best. You have made my week. I would buy you a beer if I could. I would buy you ALL of the beer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the name of your script (fasta_corrector9.pl), and the format of your files, I am going to assume that you're doing something with FASTA sequences. If that's true, I think you should really get to understand the Bio namespace on CPAN. The whole point of having these open format specs is that people write tools to manipulate the formats and give them to you for free. In this case, you should strongly consider using [Bio::DB::Fasta](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/DB/Fasta.pm) to access your FASTA files as structured data.

```
my $stream  = Bio::DB::Fasta->new('/path/to/files')->get_PrimarySeq_stream;
while (my $seq = $stream->next_seq) {
     # now you are streaming through your FASTA sequences in order.
     # You can accomplish shuffling with O(1) space complexity in this loop. 
 }
```

Comment: @msonk: Hey, doing it the piecemeal way is fine if you are learning Perl. (@user1569630: First improvement would be to use a single array where each entry is two lines long (`push @lines, $_ while $_ = <> . <>` say).)

Comment: Oh, and by the way, OP, if you are trying to mix up a FASTA sequence line by line for some scientific purpose then you should be apprised that your methodology is insufficient for creating a sequence of random contigs and any analysis you do from such an assumption is tainted. The fact that FASTA sequences are broken up on multiple lines is an implementation detail.

Comment: +1 Assuming this Fasta module is the appropriate one for the input (I don't know), this solution is preferable, and should perhaps be the accepted answer.